# Ionic capacitor google maps appears over WebView on IOS

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

Integrated @capacitor/google-maps plugin in an Ionic capacitor application. Plugin is working fine when running the application in browser or in android. But in iOS ionic header is not visible as the plugin renders the map over the WebView.

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-toolbar class="tool" slot="fixed">
    <ion-icon
      class="back"
      name="arrow-back-circle"
      (click)="handleDismissMap()"
    ></ion-icon>
    <ion-button
      slot="end"
      shape="round"
      class="action-button"
      (click)="handleSaveLocation()"
    >
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="location-outline"></ion-icon>
      Save Location
    </ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <div id="container">
    <capacitor-google-maps id="map" #map></capacitor-google-maps>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

```
ion-content {
  --background: none;
}

body {
  background: none;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

capacitor-google-maps {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

ion-toolbar.tool {
  padding: 1rem;
  --background: transparent;

  ion-icon.back {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0.4rem 1rem 0 0;
  }

  ion-button.action-button {
    color: #1d4370 !important;
    --color: #1d4370 !important;
    --background: #fff !important;
    font-family: "Gothom Medium" !important;
    ion-icon {
      color: #1d4370 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to move the ion-toolbar outside of the ion-content. and place it inside a ion-header component. check the docs for more info.

Comment: Already tried. Not working for me. @StackoverBlows

Comment: If there is no ion-header, it will push up all the ion-content up. When inspecting the element, is your ion-toolbar and buttons there? im thinking its behind the map and you just need to give z-index: 9999; to the toolbar. this will place it above the map.

Comment: I tired with z-index: 9999; still the same. ion-header is appearing under the map view.

Comment: Add position: fixed to it as well.